# Using vscode with Jupyter extension, how to find/replace text within a notebook cell

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

In Jupyter Lab and Notebook web UI, it is possible to find and replace in the selected cell or entire notebook.

How to instruct vscode to replace only in the selected cell?
[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution? This is the only thing I am missing in Jupyter extension on Visual Studio Code. But it is really important to me. I think I will continue to use Jupyter in Browser for as long as this feature hasn't been added to Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I opened an issue in vscode for Jupyter Extension and seems is going to be implemented. Check here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141493

Comment: Solved based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73109147/1729896 `F3` key is for the cell itself