# How to find and replace text in a single cell when using Jupyter extension inside Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

As the title says, how to find and replace text inside a single jupyter cell when using the jupyter extension in Visual Studio Code? I am familiar with ctr+h but that will replace all the occurrences in the entire jupyter notebook file. This is a really important feature for me, as I am using it a lot in jupyter on the browser.

Comment: if you select the cell, then `ctrl+h`, is there a **Selection Only** button, there is in regular text files

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't see Selection only button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the first occurrence and then use `Ctrl+D`. It will select the next occurence in the cell. Repeat that until you go back to the first ocurrence and then type the new value. It will replace all the values your circled on.

In case you have changed that keyboard shortcut or if it is different you can find the correct one:

[image: shortcut]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but certainly closest possible and really useful. Thanks

Comment: I agree, not exactly the answer but I looked at an actual replace limited to the cell and couldn't find it...

Answer (score 13):

**2023-02-09 update**

For the most updated VSCode, select something you would like to replace, and then `F2`. If you want to replace all instances in the cell use `Ctrl` `F2` in the pc

[image]

---

**Original answer**

`F3` do the trick. It first shows the "Find" widget for a single cell. Then click the triangle on the left, which will be expanded to a "Replace" widget.

[image]

Comment: Seems in vscode 1.75.0 with jupyter extension v2023.2.1000391021 `F3` does not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Luis; I just updated the answer. Now it is `F2`.

Comment: `F2` let us rename but does not provide the same functionality as `F3` before the change that we were able to find and replace in the context of the Jupyter cell. I missed that feature, I will try to open a GitHub issue.

Comment: I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12804)

Answer (score 2):

try select a cell and use `Ctrl+g` as I just found out accidentally.

Comment: Cmd+g works fine on MacOS

Comment: This does not work for me (VSode 1.76.2), F3 used to work as described above, but also not anymore.

Comment: Cmd+g no longer works for me (VSCode 1.87.0) 

Comment: The vsc (version 1.87.2) command `editor.action.rename` allows you to replace all occurrences of a highlighted string within a cell. By default it is bound to `F2`, but can easily re-bound to another key. This is equivalent to a Replace-All.